# jquery checkbox with limit dinamis

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have following html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans" data-stok="[1]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 1
  <input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans" data-stok="[4]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 2
  <input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans" data-stok="[0]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 3
```

jquery :

```
function ambil(x){
    var limit = x.data('stok')
    var cnt = $('#perlengkapans:checked').length
    if (cnt>limit){
        x.prop('checked', '')
        alert('you can maximum '+ limit)
    }
}
```

I want to show a message as `"you can maximum <variable_limit_value>"`, if the stock has reached the limit.
But it is not showing the message. Please help.

Comment: `perlengkapans` this id should be unique. use class instead and use it as selector

Comment: Question has unclear sound. Provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Change Input attribute - `onchange="ambil((this))"`

And your function to -

```
function ambil(x) {
        limit = $(x).data('stok')
        cnt = $('#perlengkapans:checked').length
        if (cnt > parseInt(limit,10) ) {
            $(x).prop('checked', '')
            alert('you can maximum ' + limit)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you are achieving with you code.

But, depending upon your code, following are corrections:

1) In HTML DOM, there should be only one id for one element. In short `id` is a unique property. In your case, there were three elements with same `id`. Need to fix it.

2) Change `id` property to `name` and access the same. There can be multiple elements with same name.

Corrected Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="[1]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="[4]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="[0]" onchange="ambil($(this))"> name item 3
<script>
  function ambil(x){
    var limit = x.data('stok')
    var cnt = $('[name=perlengkapans]:checked').length; // observe what is changed here.
    if (cnt>limit){
    x.prop('checked', '')
    alert('you can maximum '+ limit)}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IDs should not be repeated and the logic seems to be wrong. Try something like below.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans1" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="1" value="name item 1" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans2" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="4" value="name item 2" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="perlengkapans3" name="perlengkapans" data-stok="0" value="name item 3" />
```

In js file add this

```
$("input[name='perlengkapans']").on("change", function(){
    if($("input[name='perlengkapans']":checked").length > $(this).data('stok')) {
           // Display Alert
       }             
    });
});
```